# Linking g++ 4.8 to libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, libstdc++

I downloaded and built gcc 4.8.1 on my desktop, running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04. I built it out of source, like the docs recommend, and with the commands

```
../../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=$HOME --program-suffix=-4.8
make
make -k check
make install
```

It seemed to pass all the tests, and I installed everything into my home directory w/ the suffix -4.8 to distinguish from the system gcc, which is version 4.6.3.

Unfortunately when I compile c++ programs using g++-4.8 it links to the system libc and libstdc++ rather than the newer ones compiled from gcc-4.8.1. I downloaded and built gcc 4.8 because I wanted to play around with the new C++11 features in the standard library, so this behaviour is definitely not what I wanted. What can I do to get gcc-4.8 to automatically link to the standard libraries that came with it rather than the system standard libraries?

Comment: libc is nothing to do with GCC, so there is no "newer one compiled with gcc-4.8.1", it's supposed to link to the system libc. Presumably when you say it links to the system libstdc++ you mean it links correctly but fails to run, due to incorrect libstdc++ version?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you link with your own gcc you need to add an extra run-time linker search path(s) with `-Wl,-rpath,$(PREFIX)/lib64` so that at run-time it finds the shared libraries corresponding to your gcc.

I normally create a wrapper named `gcc` and `g++` in the same directory as `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8` which I invoke instead of `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8`, as prescribed in [Dynamic linker is unable to find GCC libraries](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#rpath):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ${0}SUFFIX -Wl,-rpath,PREFIX/lib64 "$@"
```

When installing `SUFFIX` and `PREFIX` should be replaced with what was passed to `configure`:

```
cd ${PREFIX}/bin && rm -f gcc g++ c++ gfortran
sed -e 's#PREFIX#${PREFIX}#g' -e 's#SUFFIX#${SUFFIX}#g' gcc-wrapper.sh > ${PREFIX}/bin/gcc
chmod +x ${PREFIX}/bin/gcc
cd ${PREFIX}/bin && ln gcc g++ && ln gcc c++ && ln gcc gfortran
```

(`gcc-wrapper.sh` is that bash snippet).

---

The above solution does not work with some versions of `libtool` because `g++ -Wl,... -v` assumes linking mode and fails with an error.

A better solution is to use specs file. Once gcc/g++ is built, invoke the following command to make gcc/g++ add `-rpath` to the linker command line (replace `${PREFIX}/lib64` as necessary):

```
g++ -dumpspecs | awk '/^\*link:/ { print; getline; print "-rpath=${PREFIX}/lib64", $0; next } { print }' > $(dirname $(g++ -print-libgcc-file-name))/specs
```

Comment: As well as that FAQ entry see [How do I insure that the dynamically linked library will be found?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths) and [Finding Dynamic or Shared Libraries](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic) ... turns out RTFM answers this question :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I would really like to see instructions how to modify the spec file so that gcc adds rpath automatically. Modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is too manual and unreliable for me.

Comment: IIRC Nasanov is the man to ask, I think he does that when building gcc from pkgsrc.  It's quite simple for a non-multilib gcc, but is trickier when you want it to add `lib` or `lib64` depending on the multilib target.  I'll dig out some relevant links and email you later ...

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53002 for the solution to the multilib problem and http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45508#c10 for a possible future solution

Comment: @JonathanWakely RTFM is right. Unfortunately the manual is huge, I missed the relevant FAQ, and I didn't realize it was the dynamic linker that was giving me the problems. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826585/how-to-configure-libstdc-with-gcc-4-8?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718753/custom-built-gcc-4-6-0-on-ubuntu-11-04-links-wrong-libstdc?rq=1 ask essentially the same question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks a lot Jon, the first link looks promising, I'll play with it. I already patch gold to support `LD_RUN_PATH` when building my toolchain, so adding another patch is easy, but I digress.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin So is the idea that that `g++ -dumpspecs` command only applies the path to that particular `g++` versus applying it to any `g++` on the system if you had set it in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @DavidDoria Not sure I understand your question. The idea is to add `-rpath` to linker commands of this gcc. Only the binaries produced by this `gcc` are affected.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I'm just trying to underand if this "non-system wide" behavior is the advantage of the -dumpspecs method vs other methods of getting this to work (like LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16826679/284529)

Comment: @DavidDoria It is the correct way of specifying non-standard paths to shared libraries, unlike `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem when building gcc-4.8.2.  I don't have root access on that machine and therefore need to install to my home directory.  It took several attempts before I figured out the magic required to get this to work so I will reproduce it here so other people will have an easier time.  These are the commands that I used to configure gcc:

```
prefix=/user/grc/packages

export LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,$prefix/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH=$prefix/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$prefix/lib

../../src/gmp-4.3.2/configure  --prefix=$prefix
../../src/mpfr-2.4.2/configure --prefix=$prefix
../../src/mpc-0.8.1/configure  --prefix=$prefix --with-mpfr=$prefix --with-gmp=$prefix
../../src/gcc-4.8.2/configure  --prefix=$prefix --with-mpfr=$prefix --with-gmp=$prefix --with-mpc=$prefix --enable-languages=c,c++
```

That got me a working binary but any program I built with that version of g++ wouldn't run correctly unless I built it with the -Wl,-rpath,$prefix/lib64 option.  It is possible to get g++ to automatically add that option by providing a specs file.  If you run

```
strace g++ 2>&1 | grep specs
```

you can see which directories it checks for a specs file.  In my case it was $prefix/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/specs so I ran g++ -dumpspecs to create a new specs file:

```
cd $prefix/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2
$prefix/bin/g++ -dumpspecs > xx
mv xx specs
```

and then edited that file to provide the -rpath option.  Search for the lines like this:

```
*link_libgcc:
%D
```

and edit to add the rpath option:

```
*link_libgcc:
%D -rpath /user/grc/packages/lib/%M
```

The %M expands to either ../lib or ../lib64 depending on whether you are building a 32-bit or a 64-bit executable.

Note that when I tried this same trick on an older gcc-4.7 build it didn't work because it didn't expand the %M.  For older versions you can remove the %M and just hardcode lib or lib64 but that is only a viable solution if you only ever build 32-bit executables (with lib) or only ever build 64-bit executables (with lib64).

Comment: You're making your life unnecessarily complicated installing gmp, mpfr and mpc manually and then having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find them, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662297/981959

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I must have missed that nugget 4.5 year's ago in the gcc build instructions.  Nice to know for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

**`gcc -print-search-dirs`** will tell you where your compiler is looking for runtime libraries, etc. You can override this with the **`-B<prefix>`** option.

Comment: GCC will look for the right libraries automatically at link-time, the problem is that the dynamic linker doesn't use the same paths at run-time, and using `-B` can't change that

Comment: @JonathanWakely - well, the OP claims otherwise: *"Unfortunately when I compile c++ programs using g++-4.8 it links to the system libc and libstdc++..."* - you'll have to clarify it with him.

Comment: See the links in my comment on the other answer, this is a FAQ. The compiler links to the right libraries at link-time, but it's up to the user to ensure the same libraries are used again at run-time.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - ah. I see what you mean. Without `-rpath` options, it will just look for the first `libstdc++.x.so` in the ld.so cache, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` right? If I spend too long on SO, I tend to get tunnel vision.

Comment: Exactly right, and if that libstdc++.so is not the one the binary was originally linked to it'll fail to run