# GCC specs file: how to get the installation path

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Instead of giving `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/local/gcc52/lib64` to each invocation of GCC 5.2 which I built from the source, I modified its `spec` file in this way:

```
*link_command:
%{!fsyntax-only:%{!c:%{!M:%{!MM:%{!E:%{!S:    %(linker) -rpath=%:getenv(HOME /local/gcc52/lib64) ...
```

But this depends on my specific installation under `$HOME/local/gcc52`.  Are there better way to refer to the installation path of the invoked GCC itself?

This manual page did not help me much:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html

Comment: Sometimes `-L` is required along with `-Wl,-rpath`. So I guess the broader question is: after installing the compiler locally, how do we get everything to 'just work' on this one machine, ignoring the system libraries/headers?

Comment: Have you tried with a specs file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224826 presents a solution for creating a spec file with the right path after GCC has been installed. The spec file would need recreating if you move the GCC installation later.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for the info, but that's actually a bad news for me because both that guy and I independently reached to the conclusion that the specs file had to be tweaked per installation (though that doesn't eliminate the possibility of finding a portable solution.)

Comment: @nodakai When you’re compiling GCC, you can specify `--with-specs` to `configure`. You already need to specify the `--prefix`, so that shouldn’t be any more difficult. Unrelated to that, I’m curious about your spec string: why do you modify `link_command` instead of just `link`? I haven’t thoroughly tested it yet, but with a small amount of testing I’ve done so far it looks like just adding the line `*link: + %{!static:-rpath PREFIX/lib64 -enable-new-dtags}`, where PREFIX is whatever you pass to `--prefix`, does the job.

Comment: @nodakai Update: The `--with-specs` option didn’t work the way I thought, but if you work with spec files I still think modifying the `link` string and using the appending feature with `+` is a better option.

Comment: @DanielH Thank you for the info, let me see how it fits with my use cases.

Answer (score 4):

When you’re compiling GCC, you need to pass the prefix you want to `configure` anyway. At that time, you can also give it the `--with-specs` option. Based on my experiments, the option `--with-specs='%{!static:%x{-rpath='$prefix'/lib64} %x{-enable-new-dtags}}'` (where `$prefix should be replaced by the same path you pass to`--prefix`) works (you need something more complicated for multilib support, of course).

Things to note:

- This isn’t properly documented anywhere, but it appears that, unlike with regular [spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html), the `--with-specs` configure option applies to the command-line arguments passed to GCC itself. Thus, you can’t just try to modify the `*link` spec string.
- The `%x` sequence doesn’t change the GCC command line, but accumulates arguments to pass to the linker. That’s why I pass `-rpath` and `-enable-new-dtags` directly instead of via `-Wl`.
- There are a bunch of suggestions online for what specs to pass. I didn’t see this one anywhere, so it take it with a grain of salt. The reason I used my own is that all the others either modify a spec string like `*link`, which you cannot do with `--with-specs`, or they add options to the GCC command line using `-Wl`, which I’m fairly sure somebody said they had trouble with because in some cases it confused GCC when they weren’t linking. YMMV.
- If you use bootstrapping (which you usually are unless building a cross-compiler, in which case I could be wrong but I don’t think this particular rpath trick is useful anyway), this will add a `RUNPATH` to the GCC programs and shared libraries as well. This seems to be the correct option, because they were compiled against the libraries that are now in `$prefix/lib64`, but it’s worth noting.
- I added `-enable-new-dtags`, which puts this in `DT_RUNPATH` instead of `DT_RPATH`. This is the newer attribute which all the documentation says should be preferred, <sarcasm>which is why it requires an extra flag which isn’t clearly cross-referenced in the docs</sarcasm>. Among the differences between RPATH and RUNPATH are:

  - If RUNPATH is present, RPATH will be completely ignored.
  - The RPATH overrides `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; the RUNPATH does not.
  - They work somewhat differently for dependencies of dependencies (`RUNPATH` is only searched for direct dependencies; `RPATH` is searched for indirect dependencies as long as nothing in the dependency chain has a `RUNPATH`). More details are available [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/10/28/rpath-and-runpath/).
  - I think that’s everything, but I wouldn’t be surprised if I’m missing something.

  As the article I linked above indicates, not everybody prefers RUNPATH to RPATH, but here it shouldn’t be an issue unless you mix code from different compilers requiring different compiler support libraries in a complicated way, and if you do that I don’t think there’s any one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, GCC is very much dependent on the installation folder it was compiled for. I build RTEMS cross-compilation toolchains very frequently, and one of the first things I learned was that there are **many** places in the generated cross-compiler where the installation prefix (i.e. whatever was passed to `--exec-prefix`) is "burned" in.

"Learned" - as in, I tried to move the compiler's folder to a different path, and all hell broke loose :-)

My point: modifying `specs` files to make them point to paths in your install seems absolutely normal, as far as GCC is concerned.

Comment: Check out musl-cross for a counter-example.